# JDO and Google App Engine datastore: key representation in code

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have just finished watching the following videos in an attempt to
understand JDO and Google App Engine datastore:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jW2iSKDipY
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yl_J-UYE94w
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzctc48c0BM
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx5gdoNpcZM

Now I wonder, take the example where we have an entity of kind Grandparent
having an entity of kind Parent having an entity of kind Child as in one of
the videos. The key for one of the the Child entities could be:

```
Grandparent:Jane/Parent:Jack/Child:Joe
```

1. How do I code the class for this instance in JDO (presumably there will be
   three classes) but I would like to see an implementation where we can see
   the key values set as part of the key explicitly. Any ideas?
2. I also wonder, what is the difference between using JDOQL to access my
   data and iterating through the various instances using iterators programmatically?

Thanks,

John Goche

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There a more concrete example in the App Engine datastore java documentation: [Child Objects and Relationships](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html#Child_Objects_and_Relationships)
2. You can construct Datastore queries using JDOQL string syntax and by calling methods on `Query` objects, there is no difference when accessible the data both will return a `Collection`, you can see more concrete examples in [Introducing Queries in JDO](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries.html#Introducing_Queries)

Comment: I was aware of 1. but there the Key is automatically generated and I wanted to somehow construct it myself so that it corresponds to Grandparent:Jane/Parent:Jack/Child:Joe, rather than it containing some random data, but it seems this is not possible with JDO. As for 2. I was just wondering, if I need to traverse the whole collection rather than just have a few instances returned, I may as well do without JDOQL as performance will not be affected. Thanks, John Goche